# Кастомизация System UI

Tags: android

Кастомизирую System UI,хочу поменять цвет шторки и всего остального в ней

AOSP

Цвет фона меняется замечательно, (переопределяем цвет или подкладываем свой ресурс)

```
 <com.android.systemui.qs.QSContainerImpl
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/quick_settings_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false" >

    <!-- Main QS background -->
<!--@drawable/qs_background_primary -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/quick_settings_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/qs_background_primary" />
```

Но цвет аватаров (Wi-fi,Bluetooth, фонарик и т.д.) никак не хотят меняться.
Пробовал подменять цвета, создавать кастомные стили, ковырял xml файлы но безуспешно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Мы меняли system UI для Android 4.4. Там был framework-res.apk в system,  если не ошибаюсь, там внутри были системные ресурсы(всякие dimens, strings и т.д., может вам тоже нужно там покопатся?).

Comment: Все изменения я заливаю через Overlay, исходники я беру в framework, там есть все и цвет фона и аватаров и тд. но изменения цвета аватаров не как не реагирует в моем коде.